# Invalid argument error with printf and strftime

Tags: c++, logging

Let's say I have a program that writes something to the log file. Everything worked fine until I decided to add a timestamp to the filename.

Here's how i do this:

```
time_t rawtime;
struct tm * timeinfo;
char buffer[80];
time(&rawtime);
timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d-%m-%Y_%I:%M:%S_", timeinfo);

std::string timestring(buffer);
std::string filename = timestring + ".txt";

std::cout << "\n" << filename << std::endl;

FILE *f = fopen(filename.c_str(), "w");
```

I don't know why, but `fopen` returns `NULL`.

`filename` is okay: `20-08-2017_01:08:09.txt`, but if I change the filename to `logfile.txt` for example - eveything works fine.

It's as if some characters were not allowed to be in the filename, but I tested it with `-`, `_`, `:` and that's not the case.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: What operating system? If Windows, then `:` doesn't seem to be allowed. Are you sure you've tested properly?

Comment: Win 8.1, VS2015, Intel Compiler 17.0.

Comment: Can you create the same file by hand?

Comment: Try googling "colon in filename".

Comment: Okay guys, you were right. Somehow I overlooked it with `:`. Thanks.

Comment: The list of illegal characters is documented on MSDN: [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces - Naming Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx#naming_conventions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try escaping the : character, that might be the problem